# Pivot Table - Display Grand Total only for specific columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

When using a pivot table, if you have Grand Totals displayed, it displays them for all fields that are being summarized.

How can I display the grand total for only certain fields.

For example, in the image below, I only want to see the grand total for `Amount` and not `Cost`.

Is this possible ?

[image]

I currently have to use conditional formatting to look for the row containing 'Grand Total' and then format text in that row to the same colour as the cell fill etc.

Comment: Results are calculated or not calculated. No separate settings for each separate result. Hiding is safe solution I think.

Comment: Or, stick your own summation under the columns you choose.